# Azure Data Factory - calculate the number of days between two dates

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have to calculate the number of days between two dates and I search and I don't find any similar function available in ADF.

[image]

what I've noticed so far is that if I want to get the number of days between 2 columns, it means that the columns must be date columns, but I have timestamp columns (date + time)

how can I transform these columns into Date columns? or do you have other idea?

Comment: Are these columns in a table in a SQL database?  If so, you would probably be best off using the built-in SQL function `DATEDIFF` to do this, eg `DATEDIFF( day, dateCol1, dateCol2 )`

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that `86,400` is the number of seconds in a day

> Now, using the function
> [ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#ticks),
> it returns the ticks property value for a specified timestamp. A tick
> is a 100-nanosecond interval.

```
@string(div(sub(ticks(last_date),ticks(first_date)),864000000000))
```

Can re-format any type timestamp using function `formatDateTime()`

```
@formatDateTime(your_time_stamp,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

### Example:

[image]
[image]

> @string(div(sub(ticks('2022-02-23 15:58:16'),ticks('2022-01-31 15:58:16')),864000000000))

[image]

Comment: Thank you. One more question: is there any chance of getting the number of days exactly as you showed me, but using Data Flows instead of Pipeline?

Comment: @Ana-MariaLudu hey, did you find a way to do it using data flow?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expression that I used for *Data Flow*.

`toDate(toString({max_po create date},'yyyy-MM-dd'))` - `toDate(toString(max_datetimetoday,'yyyy-MM-dd'))`

`max_po`,  `create date` and `max_datetimetoday` are `TimeStamp(date + time)` columns.

The result is in days.